# Is this Overloading, methods with same name in different classes and different signature?

Tags: java, oop, overloading

If I have the following code in Java:

```
class A {

    public int add(int a , int b) {
        return (a+b);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public float add(float a , float b) {
        return (a+b);
}
```

In this particular case the sub-class isn't exactly overriding the base class's `add` function as they have different signatures and the concept of overloading occurs only if they are in the same scope. So, is the function `add(float , float)` in the sub-class `B` treated as an entirely new function and the concept of overloading and overriding is not applicable to it? And does it use 'Static binding' or 'Dynamic Binding'?

Comment: Very ilustrative: https://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/overriding-and-overloading-in-java-with-examples/

Answer (score 4):

Method add in class b is an **overload** of add in class a. Not an **override**. An override would just be a different implementation of the original add method.

Comment: But I knew that the concept of Overloading comes in play if and only if the functions are in the same scope or class. This is what created the confusion

Answer (score 2):

In brief, yes. To *override*, you need to replicate the complete method signature, which includes the method name, parameters and return types. From [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

> An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus
>   the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an
>   instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.

You might want to consider the [@Override annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html), which will trigger a compiler error if you don't successfully overrride a method.

In this particular instance, it perhaps looks like you don't need overriding so much as some solution including generics. So you could instantiate a class `a<Integer>` and a similar class `a<Float>`

Comment: So you are saying that add(float , float) in class b is an entirely different function and has nothing do with the add function in class a. In which case , overloading nor overriding is into play here.

Comment: Maybe. You're not overriding, and you're providing a different class with an overloaded method alongside the original, so perhaps a generics solution is more appropriate here

Answer (score 2):

In that case you are not **overriding** the method, since the signatures are different.

But there is **overloading** in class b, since you have two methods with the same name but different parameters (one if class a, and the other one in class b)

Hope it helps.

Comment: But I knew that the concept of Overloading comes in play if and only if the functions are in the same scope or class. This is what created the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a method that is not overridden but overloaded in the subclass. Here the subclass has two add() methods. The version which accepts int arguments(not overridden), and the overloaded method add() which accepts float arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this particular case neither overloading nor overriding occurs, because return type must be same in case overloading and overriding, so neither static binding nor dynamic binding happens in this case.
method overloading is not possible in case of different return type, because compiler can't figure that which method he need to call.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late answer but i think it's important question need to be answered for beginners.

**One key point in overloading is it works in inheritance.**

Next is either it's `Static binding` or `Dynamic binding`.

It is **Static Binding** So, why?

**Static Binding**

1. Static binding in Java occurs during `Compile time`.
2. `private`, `final` and `static` methods and variables uses static binding and bonded by compiler.
3. Static binding uses Type (class in Java) information for binding.

**Dynamic Binding**

4. Dynamic binding occurs during `Runtime`.
5. Dynamic methods bonded during runtime based upon runtime object.
6. Dynamic binding uses Object to resolve binding.

**But the important part is here**

> Overloaded methods are bonded using static binding while overridden methods are bonded using dynamic binding at runtime.

Java compiler determines correct version of the overloaded method to be executed at compile time based upon the type of argument used to call the method and parameters of the overloaded methods of both these classes receive the values of arguments used in call and executes the overloaded method.

```
B a=new B();
a.add(4, 5);
a.add(4.0f, 5.0f);
```

So if you will create reference of type B then it will search for proper argument type
and for above code it will execute both methods.

```
A a=new B();
a.add(4, 5);
a.add(4.0f, 5.0f);
```

but for above code it will give compile time error for float arguments.

Hope it clears all doubts.

Answer (score 0):

First things first

**Is it method overriding ?**

No , since to override a method you need to replicate the complete method signature as pointed out in Brian Agnew's answer and as I explain below.

**Is it overloading ?**

Yes , Method "add" has an overloaded implementation in Class B.

Consider the following code:

```
class C{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        B a = new B();
        a.add(2 , 3);
        a.add(2.0 , 3.0);
    }
}

class A {

    public int add(int a , int b) {
        System.out.print("INT ");
        return a + b;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public double add(double a , double b) {
        System.out.print("Double ");
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

> OUTPUT : INT Double

So , the method in Class B in your code overloads the add method that it inherits from its parent

**Does it use Static Binding or Dynamic Binding ?**

This is what makes me conclude that OP is confused.It is static binding because it is a overloaded function. The only way to think of dynamic binding would have been in below scenario

```
class C{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a = new B();
        a.add(2.0 , 3.0);
    }
}

class A {

    public int add(int a , int b) {
        System.out.println("A : INT");
        return a + b;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public int add(int a , int b) {
        System.out.println("B : INT");    
        return a + b;
    }
        
    public double add(double a , double b) {
        System.out.println("Double");
        return a + b;
    }   
}
```

> Output : B : INT

Here , the parent class A has a contract that says  , "I have an add behaviour for ints" . class B inherits this add behaviour and makes it more specific and at the same time also provides a new behaviour where it can add doubles.
But class A has "no knowledge of this behaviour".

So an object of class A "cannot" add doubles. To do that you need a more specific type of A object i.e. a B object.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29974730)

Answer (score -1):

The method `add()` in class A is also available to class B by inheritance, therefore the method is `overloaded` in class by changing the data type from `int, int` to `float, float`.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, I think. The asker knows about overloading and overriding.

Answer (score -1):

The concept of Overloading comes in play if and only if the functions are in the same scope or class.
cz if this is the case of method overloading then for same method signature or same argument type the compiler gets confuse and must give compile time error .
but in the above program in class B if you pass the same argument in same order then according to overloading it must give error but it is not happening u can check it i already have.
It is the case of inheritance where through object reference if you call any method then the compiler will check it in child class ,if its not there then it will look into parent class that the above program is all about.
hope this is helpfull.

Comment: Please work on capitalization and punctuation. This answer is quite difficult to understand